# Read file from gridfs in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I have this route for this task:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var gfs;
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var connection = mongoose.createConnection(mongodb://localhost/images);
connection.once('open', function () {
    gfs = Grid(connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
});
app.get('/api/image/:file', function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', getType(req.params.file));
    gfs.createReadStream({
        filename: '/api/image/'+req.params.file
    }).pipe(res);
});
```

For some reason it's really slow, can't figure why is that. Even when i run it on local. If i use something like mongoose-fs or something familiar it will be faster?
Also every time image is loading, it don't keep that image in cache(every time is 200). How can i tell to node that this have to be cached? At the moment i have express way `app.set('view cache', true);`.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I spent quite a bit of time with GridFS then moved to AWS S3 for static files with node `aws-sdk` and have been very happy.

Comment: Yeah, i don't want to use something else :)

Comment: You need to determine why the slowdown is occurring so you'll have to something like top. Are you paging out and writing to disk when you read the file, this could be caused by a large image on a machine with low memory.

Comment: Even on my local pc, where i have allot of memory it is slow. Also, reminding about  the cache, do you know why it's not getting cached?

Comment: Try to use mongoose.connect()... I've read that there's significant differences in some "core" functions depending on what you want to do...Maybe it helps?

Comment: So the basic ask is, "images", How large are they? Are these images over 16MB? I have photoshop documents here that are smaller than that at pretty high res. So the very valid question here is *"Exactly what is the average size of the image data you are talking about here?"*. Even if you don't think it's valid it "really" is. So the information is pretty much a requirement here.

Comment: Average size is 4mb, but because of limit of 16mb i used GridFS.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: No :)
Using other service for hosting files now.